Dynamically read value of variable from shell
In Spring, I know I can use the @Value annotation to read the value of a shell variable, e.g.,
public class MyClass {
    @Value("${SHELL_VAR})
    String shellVariable;
    
    public String getShellVar() {
        return shellVariable;
    }
}

But then the value of SHELL_VAR is read only once from the shell. I want a way to read SHELL_VAR each time I call getShellVar(), since it changes over time.

What is changing over time exactly? The environment associated with the running process is not modified if you change an environment variable in another process.

@aled this is based on a project at my work and I don’t fully understand how it works, but I think a shell script file containing the variables changes every day and is loaded, possibly by the program.

When you do ${SHELL_VAR} you're loading an environment variable. These variables for one process are only inherited from the process that started them, plus any they define themselves. When you start a terminal/shell, you start a program that will inherit environment variables (and set many of its own). Launching further programs from this will provide them with the current shell's variables. An un-called script will have no effect on actively loaded/set environment variables (w/o something executing that does load them).

It doesn't matter what language or code you are using. In the common operating systems today like Windows, Linux, macOS, etc. when a process is launched it receives a copy of the environment variables it is going to use while executing. If you change the shell script that sets a variable and launches a program, it will affect the following executions, not the already running ones. Because of that it is not just possible to read updated values during execution. You may want to use a different method to send updated values to a running application, like configuration files, a database or some service that is queried by the application during execution time.
